# Cant import function to pytest file

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing

I have a directory structure like follows -

```
jobs/
  src/
    main/
      airflow-dags/
        __init__.py
        create_table.py
tests/
  test_create_table.py
```

My `test_create_table.py` file

```
import pytest
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(1, 'jobs/src/main/airflow-dags')
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
from create_table import create_table_func


class TestCreatePartitionTable:
    def test_create_table(self):
        return True
```

I can't seem to import my `create_table` file so I can run tests on the functions for this file.  I have added both those `sys` inserts that I found while searching for a solution, but neither is working.  I tried both of them individually as well, no luck.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Package names are relative to the project root by default, so you need something like this:

```
from jobs.src.main.airflow-dags.create_table import create_table_func
```

However, the `-` in `airflow-dags` causes a problem because python doesn't allow a dash in a package name. I suggest renaming it to `airflow_dags`.

Comment: That is not an option, there is an enterprise wide requirement for naming it that way.  Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: @asdasd32 Are you saying your company requires you to use a dash in the folder name rather than an underscore? Your company can require it all they want, but python doesn't allow dashes in package names.

Comment: No I mean that folder structure is required.